# ASP.NET Mvc Website freeze when connecting to external Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Today I came up with something really strange with our Website.
We had performance issues. The Asp.NET Mvc web on IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008) got frozen every X Time.
Its a normal E-Commerce system which connects to MSSQL Server on same Infastructure.
But When you go into an Detailed page of a Product we ask the Stock via AJAX after page got loaded,
we have 2 Warehouses on which we have to ask the Stock.

Today the other warehouse got Server problems and the connection from our e-commerce website to this server (external and simple connection with 1 query to ask the stock) got timedout every connection made to this server. But as I said, this external server isnt involved with nothing more as the query in ajax call.

The strange thing is, all Users (whole IIS Pool) gets frozen when establishing connection to this external server. After connection timeout all requests gets processed, but not until then.

Is it normal? I thought all requests are done in a own "thread".
P.D. its not a Linked Server or something else. Its a direct connection to there and 1 Query, nothing more.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Connection pool might be getting full when it's waiting for a timeout. It defaults to 100 active connections. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: Its a different Connection pool (not the same as the e-commerce CnString)

Comment: Look at performance counters for connection pools when you are observing the behavior. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* reasons that this could happen given the very general description of the architecture and limited diagnostic information provided.

However, one thing comes to mind that is worth checking.  There are [only so many IIS worker threads and completion ports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268) available. If all (or very many) worker threads end up waiting for the failed connection, there would be no (or few) worker threads available to process other requests.

If you can reproduce the issue in development or QA (by e.g. intentionally misconfiguring the connection), you could try diagnosing the state of IIS.  Check out this guidance:

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/troubleshoot-iis-application-hangs-unresponsiveness/

Comment: In Development It doesnt happen (IIS Express). Reproducing the scenario with wrong connection and while trying to establish connection, the other requests get processed without any problem.

The WorkerThreads on IIS doesnt reach Max, because as I understand it would respond then with 503 Status code.